# Can i use a universal laptop charger for +10.8v 4400mah, 47wh

Tags: battery, asus-laptop, voltage, charger

I have a universal laptop adapter with listed voltage that i can set 12v/15v/16/18/19/20/24v.. i want to try it on my asus laptop with battery rating of +10.8v 4400mah, 27wh.. it's an li-ion battery. But i'm not sure if it's safe or not..

This is the universal adapter i have

Input: 110v-240v - 50/60hz 1.5A Max
Output: 12/15/16/18/19V 4.5A Max
20/24V 4A Max
https://www.lazada.com.ph/products/universal-laptop-charger-adapter-black-i1264107-s1509989.html

Comment: also https://superuser.com/questions/247312/laptop-power-supplies-does-current-matter

Comment: @Tetsujin That first one is not a dupe, it is the reverse situation. The second one is only about amperage, so does not apply either. Voting to reopen.

Comment: tbh, there's not enough information in this one to do anything other than mark it as a dupe & see if the OP will do some research. A mismatch of a single volt is very probably fine, but we have no idea what else the universal PSU supplies. Better to close as dupe to helpful info than close as 'unclear'.

Comment: I updated it pls read

Comment: Don't do it.  You need to know what voltage, amperage and polarity your laptop needs.  You risk to ruin your laptop.

Comment: Also duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1247537/19v-charger-with-10-8v-laptop-battery; identical situation.

Answer (score -1):

It cerrtainly is not safe, if that adapter permits changing the polarity.  It's not easy to repair when part of the charging circuit has been blown away.  Concerning the adapter itself: can it deliver the necessary amperage?  You should compare it with the original.